# Can I force syntax highlighting for a certain language?

Tags: support, code-formatting, markdown, syntax-highlighting

I notice that stackoverflow automatically adds syntax highlighting to code blocks. I hate this. It always applies the wrong language's highlighting to the wrong code.

Example? The [last question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30191011/carrierwave-fog-undefined-method-gsub-for-array0x000001067d4798) I've posted, of course. Because it always happens.

Is there a way to force the system to acknowledge a code block as a specific language and apply the proper highlighting? Like Github has done, as described [here](https://help.github.com/articles/github-flavored-markdown/#syntax-highlighting). If you ask me, that's how it's done! Typing one extra word is no effort at all and it looks a lot better.

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/184108/what-is-syntax-highlighting-and-how-does-it-work/184109#184109

Answer (score 9):

Yes, you can force code highlighting for specific blocks of code. A detailed explanation is available on MSE: [What is syntax highlighting and how does it work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/184108/what-is-syntax-highlighting-and-how-does-it-work)

---

The quick summary, is that you add a language hint to the top of your code block like so:

```
<!-- language: lang-or-tag-here -->

    code goes here
```

In this case, `lang-or-tag-here` would be the language you wish to use for highlighting. I'm going to guess you want `lang-ruby` so the line would be `<!-- language: lang-ruby -->`

You can find the list of supported languages [here](https://github.com/highlightjs/highlight.js/blob/master/SUPPORTED_LANGUAGES.md).

Comment: Follow-up feature-request: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/294086/shouldnt-ruby-on-rails-have-ruby-highlighting

Comment: Hint: You can also use html comments `<!---->` to split up code blocks, if you need to.

Comment: That sounds you are not properly formatting your code block. `#` is used to indicate a header level element in markdown. Make sure everything is indented 4 spaces