# Force syntax highlighting to a specific language tag

Tags: support, tags, syntax-highlighting

I just answered [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39094337/ms-access-sql-function-calls/39095666#39095666).

The user firstly tagged his question with [sql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sql), [function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/function), and [ms-access](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ms-access).

The solution to his question is to use VBA, and I have added the code to achieve it.

The problem is that my code is syntactically recognized as SQL and not VBA.

I have edited the question to add the [vba](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/vba) tag, but that doesn't change anything.

**Is there a way to force a specific language highligthing when you have a mix of several languages into the same answer?**

Comment: [Yes](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/294084/can-i-force-syntax-highlighting-for-a-certain-language).

Comment: @Glorfindel Yes that answers the question, however it doesnt work. Could you please check my answer and explain why it doesnt work? I have edited my answer to add `lang-vba` and `lang-sql` just before the 2 code blocks, and I see no changes :(

Comment: That's OK, Andre edited it to highlight properly I have understood what I should do now. Txs!